# How to set metadata to a createblockblobfrombrowserfile in azure in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I set metadata to a `createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile` method in javascript
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF6VU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a metadata variable to store your metadata object like this:

```
const metadata = {
    category: 'blabla',
    type: 'test'
}
```

and then pass it to the `createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile` call as you do in your example.

Comment: Thanks, that help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object, with the metadata property and add it as parameter in createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile.

[image]